# please explain this requestAnimationFrame idiom

Tags: javascript, html

there are a lot of places (e.g. [How to use requestAnimationFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605588/how-to-use-requestanimationframe)) that fix `window.requestAnimationFrame` as below. I do not understand why the right hand side of the assignment is wrapped in to a function call.

`window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();`

Comment: have you seen this? http://paulirish.com/i/9290.png I don't really follow but you may..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wondered the same thing before. I'm pretty sure Google just really likes closures. Granted there is not one variable in there, it's a 'safe' thing to do.

As far as I can tell, this is the exact same thing, without any change of interfering with namespaces (a general reason to use a closure like that):

```
window.requestAnimFrame = 
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
```

Comment: it just occurred to me. whoever wrote this in the first place was using some sort of translator such as coffeescript, that resulted in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

In the OP example, putting the code into the closure does nothing (at least what I am aware of :-)

Look here http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating for a similar function doing the same thing with a local variable. In this case, the variable would end up globally if it weren't inside the closure.

So there are two things involved:

- a function to embed variables so they don't become global
- executing this function immediately to run the code.

Here [Immediate functions JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364312/immediate-functions-javascript) is another discussion about these **immediate functions**.

All the best, nobi

Answer (score -2):

`requestAnimationFrame` takes one argument: the function to run. However `setTimeout` takes the function to run as well as a delay after which to run it. So while you can just assign the individual functions directly, you have to create a closure for `setTimeout` so that you can assign the second argument.

It's basically a form of [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Comment: this would be true, except the setTimeout is wrapped in it's own function already. All possible returns can handle the same argument structure.

Comment: I am referring to the outer function. The one that takes no arguments. Yes the inner one that wraps setInterval is used to curry setInterval.